# Is there a way of creating a 3 level tree of nested form inputs with each child having a dependancy?

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, multidimensional-array

##I am creating a form that should generate the following JSON object:##

```
    "items":  [
        {
          "y": data.y,
          "x": data.x,
          "myitems": [
            {
              "chiildItem1": data.chiildItem1,
              "chiildItem2": [data.chiildItem2.1, data.chiildItem2.2,data.chiildItem2.3 ],
              "chiildItem3": [data.chiildItem3.1,chiildItem3.2,chiildItem3.3]
            }
          ]
        },
{
          "y": data.y,
          "x": data.x,
          "items": [
            {
              "chiildItem1": data.chiildItem1,
              "chiildItem2": [data.chiildItem2.1, data.chiildItem2.2,data.chiildItem2.3 ],
              "chiildItem3": [data.chiildItem3.1,chiildItem3.2,chiildItem3.3]
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
```

#### My solution can generate the arrays, however, the challenge is nesting the dynamic inputs to generate the above object. I am using react hooks below is the code that generates the dynamic field arrays

```
const [myitems, setMyitems] = useState([]);
const [counter, setCounter] = useState(0);

const addMyitems = () => {
  setMyitems(prevRisks => [...prevRisks, counter]);
  setCounter(prevCounter => prevCounter + 1);
};

const removeMyitems = index => () => {
  setMyitems(prevRisks => [...prevRisks.filter(item => item !== index)]);
  setCounter(prevCounter => prevCounter - 1);
};

const clearMyitems = () => {
  setMyitems([]);
};

{risks.map(index => {
                      const fieldName = `myItems[${index}]`;
                      return (
                        <fieldset name={fieldName} key={fieldName}>
                          <div className="row">
                            <div className="col-sm-6">
                              <Form.Group>
                                <label>x-item <span className="text-primary">{index}</span></label>
                                <textarea
                                  className="form-control"
                                  type="text"
                                  name={`${fieldName}.x`}
                                  {...register(`${fieldName}.x`, { required: false})}
                                  placeholder={`Enter item${index}`}
                                  rows="3"
                                />
                              </Form.Group>
                            </div>
                            <div className="col-sm-6">
                              <Form.Group>
                                <label>Assumption for risk <span className="text-primary">{index}</span></label>
                                <textarea
                                  className="form-control"
                                  type="text"
                                  name={`${fieldName}.y`}
                                  {...register(`${fieldName}.y`, { required: false})}
                                  placeholder={`Enter y -item for x${index}`}
                                  rows="3"
                                />
                              </Form.Group>
                            </div>
                          </div>
                          <Button className="btn btn-danger mr-2" style={{marginBottom:"10px"}} onClick={removeRisk(index)}>
                            Remove y-item{index}
                          </Button>
                        </fieldset>
                      );
                    })}
```

###How can i nest the other input fields as arrays###

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this:

Loop through each arrays to load your parent/child array item values in input boxes.
Then use the sample function below, to handle 'onChange' event of the inputs dynamically, based on the array indexes of each parent & child nested arrays.

Example items array:

```js
let items = [
    {
        "y": "test1",
        "x": "test2",
        "myItems": [
            {
                "chiildItem1": "111",
                "chiildItem2": [ "222", "333", "444" ],
                "chiildItem3": [ "555", "666", "777" ]
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "y": "test3",
        "x": "test4",
        "myItems": [
            {
            "chiildItem1": "aaa",
            "chiildItem2": [ "bbb", "ccc", "ddd" ],
            "chiildItem3": [ "eee", "fff", "ggg" ]
            }
        ]
    }
];
```

UI:

```html
<table>
  <tbody>
    {items.map((item, index) =>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <input value={item.x} onChange={(e)=> this.handleOnChange(e, 1, "x", index)} />
        </td>
        <td>
          <input value={item.y} onChange={(e)=> this.handleOnChange(e, 1, "y", index)} />
        </td>
        <td>
          <table>
            <tbody>
              {item.myItems.map((level2Item, level2Index) =>
                <tr>
                  <td>
                    <input 
                      value={level2Item.childItem1} 
                      onChange={(e)=> this.handleOnChange(e, 2, "childItem1", index, level2Index)} 
                    />
                  </td>
                  <td>
                    <table>
                      <tbody>
                        {level2Item.childItem2.map((level3Item, level3Index) =>
                          <tr>
                            <td>
                              <input 
                                value={level3Item[level3Index]} 
                                onChange={(e)=> this.handleOnChange(e, 3, "childItem2", index, level2Index, level3Index)} 
                              />
                            </td>
                          </tr>
                        )}
                      </tbody>
                    </table>
                  </td>
                  <td>{/* other item(s) */}</td>
                </tr>
              )}
            </tbody>
          </table>
        </td>
      </tr>
    )}
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Example function:

```js
handleOnChange = (event, level, field, index, level2Index="", level3Index="") => {
    var items = this.state.items;

    if (level === 1) {
        items[index][field] = event.target.value;
    }
    else if (level === 2) {
        items[index].myItems[level2Index][field] = event.target.value;
    }
    else if (level === 3) {
        items[index].myItems[level2Index][field][level3Index] = event.target.value;
    }

    this.setState({ items: items });
}
```

Note: I have used nested tables for more clarity.
You can modify this code & logic according to your UI/code.

I did this for 3 levels of nested arrays as your question is for 3 levels. But you can use this way to handle any number of levels of nested arrays.

Comment: Thank you biberman, findlink below to the sandbox more understanding of the problem. [https://codesandbox.io/s/compassionate-jepsen-18hgd?file=/src/index.js](https://codesandbox.io/s/compassionate-jepsen-18hgd?file=/src/index.js)